# How to read U/P from ODBC 17 Driver for SQL Server object

Tags: odbc, powerbuilder-build-deploy

Scenario: Client only allows access to SQL SERVER 16 for APP IDS setup in SQL Server and connected via ODBC 17 Driver for SQL Server [ SQL Server U / P access only, no windows logon, and no trusted connections allowed]. The client sets the logon Pwd in the DSN. For now, PWD values cannot be stored in the app INI file.]

App is based on PB 7.01 Enterprise. The current connection string is as follows:

```
atr_tran.DBParm ="ConnectString='DSN=NTR_SUP_CA;UID=XXXXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXXX',ConnectOption='SQL_DRIVER_CONNECT,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT'".
```

Looking for a method that reads U/P from ODBC 17 Driver for SQL Server object and inserts it into PowerBuiilder as part of the DBParm connection string.

The client is not in favor of storing pwds in the app INI FILE. `LogID= user id for logon to the database Server LogPassword= Server logon password`

Did anyone solve this before? All replies appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Where does this "ODBC 17 Driver for SQL Server object" come from? Are you talking about an existing ODBC connection? If so, how is it established?

Comment: Hello Gord, The connection is an existing ODBC .connection. The driver is installed on Windows Server that hosts the PB App. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: … and that connection is created by a different application running in a separate process? If so, how does *it* determine the correct credentials to use?